# Regarding the Existence of Approximate Identities for C$^{*}$-Algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

I am confused about one part in a proof on page 78 of Murphy's book. Let $A$ be a C$^{*}$-algebra and let $\Lambda=\{a\in A:a\geq 0\text{ and }\|a\|<1\}$. While proving that $A$ is upwards directed, Murphy states the following:

> Observe that if $a\in A^{+}$, then $a(1_{\widetilde{A}}+a)^{-1}$ belongs to $\Lambda$ (use the Gelfand representation applied to the C$^{*}$-algebra generated by $1_{\widetilde{A}}$ and $a$).

I understand the hint: using the spectral mapping theorem, I can prove that $\sigma_{\widetilde{A}}(a(1_{\widetilde{A}}+a)^{-1})\subset[0,1]$, but this shows that $a(1_{\widetilde{A}}+a)^{-1}$ is positive in $\widetilde{A}$. I do not know how to prove that $a(1_{\widetilde{A}}+a)^{-1}\in A^{+}$. In fact, this seems false since $a(1_{\widetilde{A}}+a)^{-1}$ may not even be in $A$. I know in general that $A^{+}=\widetilde{A}^{+}\cap A$, but I am unsure how or if this is being used here. I would really appreciate some clarification regarding why Murphy is able to pass to the unitisation here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you consider the unitization, $A$ sits inside it as an   ideal. Also, since $a$ and $(1_{\tilde A}+a)^{-1}$ commute, you have 
$$
a(1_{\tilde A}+a)^{-1}=a^{1/2}(1_{\tilde A}+a)^{-1}a^{1/2}\geq0. 
$$
So $a(1_{\tilde A}+a)^{-1}\in A_+$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't believe I forgot the ideal bit.